# How to divert All incoming calls to voicemail through coding in Android

Tags: android

How to divert All incoming calls to voicemail through coding in Android? I am aware that you can set a flag for a contact which determines whether the call should be diverted to voicemail or not. ContactsContract.RawContacts has got a flag to indicate that call should be forwarded to voice mail

SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL read/write An indicator of whether calls from this raw contact should be forwarded directly to voice mail ('1') or not ('0').

However I need to send all incoming call to voice mail.

Thanks,